# Last Row Returns 1 - incorrect value

Tags: excel, vba, loops

situation is following:

I have 32 columns with data (various number of rows in columns) and need to delete cells with .value "downloaded" (always last cell in a column).

I have a code looping from column 32 to 1 and searching last_row for "downloaded" value. For 30 columns code seems to be working flawlessly but 2 columns return last_row value 1 even though there are multiple values (in fact hundreds of them) but they are non existent for VBA code.

Code:

```
Last_Col = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
last_row = ws.Cells(Rows.Count & Last_Col).End(xlUp).Row

For R = Last_Col To 1 Step -1

   With ws
      Last_Col = R
      last_row = ws.Cells(.Rows.Count & Last_Col).End(xlUp).Row
      If Cells(last_row, Last_Col).Value Like "*Downloaded*" Then
         Cells(last_row, Last_Col).ClearContents
      End If
   End With

Next R
```

Data is being drained from another worksheets. For 2 columns where I experience an error, I manually deleted values and inserted another, random batch of values and code worked as intended.

Checked columns formatting, worksheets from which data is taken but I struggle to find a solution.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `ws.Cells(Rows.Count & Last_Col).End(xlUp).Row` should be `ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Last_Col).End(xlUp).Row`.  And qualify _all_ `Celks` and `Rows` with `ws`

Comment: Do you know that the like operator is case-sensitive i.e. `downloaded <> DOWNloaded`. You can use `If Instr(1, .Cells(last_row, Last_Col).Value, "Downloaded", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then` instead, if this is the issue.

Comment: Thank you Chris for correct answer as well. Could you please elaborate what's the difference between your part of code and mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Clear Last Cell If Criteria Is Met

- The main mistake was using `Cells(.Rows.Count & Last_Col)`, where `.Rows.Count & Last_Col` would have resulted in a 8 or 9-digit string, while it should have been `ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Last_Col).End(xlUp).Row` which was pointed out by `chris neilsen` in the comments.
- Another important issue is using `ws.` in front of `.cells`, `.rows`, `.columns`, `.range`, aka qualifying objects. If you don't do it and e.g. the wrong worksheet is active, you may get unexpected results.
- There is no need for looping backwards unless you are deleting.
- Although it allows wild characters (`*`, `?`), the [`Like operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator) is case-sensitive (`a<>A`) unless you use [`Option Compare Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-compare-statement).
- The first solution, using the [`End property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end), **will** fail if a number of last columns is hidden or if you insert a new first row e.g. for a title.
- The second solution, using the [`Find method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) (and the first solution), **may** fail if the data is filtered.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub clearLastEnd()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 1 To LastCol
        LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
        With ws.Cells(LastRow, c)
            If InStr(1, .Value, "Downloaded", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
               .ClearContents
            End If
        End With
    Next c
End Sub

Sub clearLastFind()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not cel Is Nothing Then
        Dim c As Long
        For c = 1 To cel.Column
            Set cel = Nothing
            Set cel = ws.Columns(c).Find(What:="*", _
                                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            If Not cel Is Nothing Then
                If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Downloaded", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                   cel.ClearContents
                Else
                  ' The current last non-empty cell does not contain criteria.
                End If
            Else
              ' Column is empty.
            End If
        Next c
    Else
      ' Worksheet is empty.
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

So you are curious why it worked at all. The following should shed a light on it:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Debug.Print "Right", "Wrong", "Rows.Count & i"
    For i = 1 To 32
        Debug.Print Cells(Rows.Count, i).Address, _
          Cells(Rows.Count & i).Address, Rows.Count & i
    Next i
End Sub
```

In a nutshell, [`Cells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells) can have 1 or 2 arguments. When 1 argument is used, it refers to the n-th cell of a range, and it 'counts' by row. The more common usage is with 2 arguments: rows, columns. For example:

```
Cells(5, 10) ' refers to cell `J5`.
```

Using one argument is inconvenient here:

```
Cells(16384 * (5-1) + 10)
```

i.e.

```
Cells(65546)
```

It may be convenient when processing a one-column or a one-row range.

Comment: Thank you for correct answer (and Chris as well). Could you please elaborate what's the difference between ws.Cells(Rows.Count & Last_Col).End(xlUp).Row and ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Last_Col).End(xlUp).Row?

Answer (score -1):

Well , let me see if i understand you have a table in worksheet table have 32 columns and X rows (because you only put WS and i can know if is WS=worksheet or WS= Table-range)
for this i am going to say is selection (if you put worksheet only hace to change for it)
in your code put:

```
Last_Col = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

but in this you always wil obtein 1st cell so i dont understand why exist?

```
WS.columns.count
```

return number of columns you selection have

```
.End(xlToLeft)
```

return last cell if star to move to left (like Ctrl - left key)
so
Last_Col ---first go to cells (1,ws.Columns.Count) then go to left (End(xlToLeft)) and the end return number of column where finish (.Column) in this case you always get cell (1,"first column of your table")
NOTE: because you wrote that you have allways value in your cells (*I have 32 columns with data (various number of rows in columns*)
And for Row you have same question

Then you Wrote you want "Delete" but in your code you put Erase value (`.ClearContents`) so what do you want? because both are no equal

BUT if you have a table and want to search in any cells that have "Download" and only want to "clear content" you just may to use "`.find`" instead; or if you want to do all at same time you can use `.replace` (need to check before if .find return "nothing" or no , because if return nothing you get error)

If you have a table with 32 columns and each row have one cell where you put "Donloaded" and want to "delete" all row your code only need select column where appear "downloaded" (example Column "status").

If you have a table where any cell can take value "downloaded" and want to "delete" that cell you need to take care to resize your table and "move to" (when you delete cells you need to say where you want to move yor data remain "letf, "rigth", "up", down).

However if you say that "Downloaded" always appear in last row you can use For to change for all columns and use .end(xlDown)

```
For i=1 to 32
if cells(1,i).end(xlDown).value="downloaded" then cells(1,i).end(xlDown).ClearContents
next
```

BUT you need put more information because if you cant garantize that all cells have values and exist cells with "nothing" you will need